SQL Sum of the same ID rows
Each service has the same price and ID. In final table I would sum quantity of the same rows - each service appear only one time and complete ID and price.
I created example table https://dbfiddle.uk/Z1EQca0b
and I can only return service name and quantity
SELECT Service_name, SUM (Qty) As Sum
FROM NewOne
GROUP BY Service_Name

Value is the result of multiplying qty and price
My table:



ID
Service_Name
Price
Qty
Value
Ident
Where




1
Repair
123.6000000000
5
618.0
123A
London


2
Collect
120.1000000000
4
480.4
127B
Paris


3
Buy
100.1000000000
14
1401.4
130C
Paris


4
Repair
123.6000000000
5
618.0
123A
Paris


5
Collect
120.1000000000
9
1080.9
127B
Rome


6
Buy
100.1000000000
12
1201.2
130C
Rome


7
Collect
120.1000000000
15
1801.5
127B
London


8
Buy
100.1000000000
1
100.1
130C
London



My expectations after query



Service_Name
Price
Qty
Value
Ident




Repair
123.6000000000
10
1236.0
123A


Collect
120.1000000000
28
3362.8
127B


Buy
100.1000000000
27
2702.7
130C




If the information is important, please include it in the question as well, not just in a fiddle

fiddle is only example to create table,
my desired result is in the question

Then please provide sample data for your question; expected results don't help us understand what your data looks like.

@ThomA they have, "My Table" - the first set of values is their sample data.

SELECT Service_Name, Price, SUM(Qty) AS Qty, SUM(Value) AS Value, Ident
FROM NewOne
GROUP BY Service_Name, Price, Ident
ORDER BY Ident ASC



SUM + GROUP BY is the way to go, so long as you have Value pre-calculated:
SELECT Service_Name, SUM(Price) AS Price, SUM(Qty) AS Qty,
    SUM(Value) AS Value, Ident
FROM NewOne
GROUP BY Service_Name, Ident


Price is still (like in 1st table)
So it is not added up
SELECT Service_Name,  Price, SUM(Qty) AS Qty,
SUM(Value) AS Value, Ident
FROM NewOne GROUP BY Service_Name, Ident, Price
It is probably solution

@Kart28 is price guaranteed to be the same for the same item? If so, add your solution as the answer.
